# Ошибка подключения к vk через vkbottle Python3

Tags: python, вконтакте

Код работает на пк, но когда закинул на pythonanywhere выбросило ошибку:

```
Task exception was never retrieved                                                                                                                                                                               
future: <Task finished name='Task-1' coro=<Bot.run_polling() done, defined at /home/v4yve/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vkbottle/framework/bot/bot.py:58> exception=ClientConnectorError(ConnectionKey(host=
'api.vk.com', port=443, is_ssl=True, ssl=None, proxy=None, proxy_auth=None, proxy_headers_hash=None), ConnectionRefusedError(111, "Connect call failed ('87.240.190.75', 443)"))>                                
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                               
  File "/home/v4yve/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 969, in _wrap_create_connection                                                                                               
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa                                                                                                                           
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1056, in create_connection                                                                                                                        
    raise exceptions[0]                                                                                                                                                                                          
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1041, in create_connection                                                                                                                        
    sock = await self._connect_sock(                                                                                                                                                                             
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 955, in _connect_sock                                                                                                                             
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)                                                                                                                                                                       
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 502, in sock_connect                                                                                                                          
    return await fut                                                                                                                                                                                             
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 537, in _sock_connect_cb                                                                                                                      
    raise OSError(err, f'Connect call failed {address}')                                                                                                                                                         
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('87.240.190.75', 443)                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                               
  File "/home/v4yve/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vkbottle/framework/bot/bot.py", line 62, in run_polling                                                                                                   
    async for event in polling.listen():  # type: ignore                                                                                                                                                         
  File "/home/v4yve/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vkbottle/polling/bot_polling.py", line 49, in listen                                                                                                      
    server = await self.get_server()                                                                                                                                                                             
  File "/home/v4yve/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vkbottle/polling/bot_polling.py", line 43, in get_server                                                                                                  
    self.group_id = (await self.api.request("groups.getById", {}))["response"][0]["id"]                                                                                                                          
  File "/home/v4yve/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vkbottle/api/api.py", line 47, in request                                                                                                                 
    response = await session.request_text(                                                                                                                                                                       
  File "/home/v4yve/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vkbottle/http/client/aiohttp.py", line 49, in request_text                                                                                                
    async with self.session.request(method, url, data=data, **kwargs) as response:                                                                                                                               
  File "/home/v4yve/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1117, in __aenter__                                                                                                              
    self._resp = await self._coro                                                                                                                                                                                
  File "/home/v4yve/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 520, in _request                                                                                                                 
    conn = await self._connector.connect(                                                                                                                                                                        
  File "/home/v4yve/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 535, in connect                                                                                                               
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)                                                                                                                                                  
  File "/home/v4yve/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 892, in _create_connection                                                                                                    
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)                                                                                                                                        
  File "/home/v4yve/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1051, in _create_direct_connection                                                                                            
    raise last_exc                                                                                                                                                                                               
  File "/home/v4yve/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1020, in _create_direct_connection                                                                                            
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(                                                                                                                                                          
  File "/home/v4yve/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 975, in _wrap_create_connection                                                                                               
    raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc                                                                                                                                                         
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.vk.com:443 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('87.240.190.75', 443)]
```

Помогите, в чем проблема? Как в библиотеке vkbottle использовать proxy?

Comment: Бесплатный тариф pythonanywhere запрещает подключения к внешним серверам

Comment: Спасибо тебе <3

Comment: Какое решение в итоге помогло?

Comment: @andreymal, vk.com (и все его поддомены) есть в [whitlelist'е](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/) сайта. Да и многие начинают запускать именно там из-за простоты использования. Проблема в чём-то другом.

Comment: @0xmeow так-то оно так, но вдруг pythonanywhere по какой-то причине не смог определить домен? По крайней мере у меня не получается придумать других причин

Comment: Вы как-то решили эту проблему?